# Finish test case method when condition is reached java testng

Tags: java, user-interface, testng

I have test method, which start GUI window and next start a endless loop. I want to finish test method when GUI is closing. Any ideas how can I reach it? I try to set a `boolean` variable and when quit button is pressed I change it to false so loop should be finish but when I look into logs test status is started.

```
boolean testRunning = true;
JButton buttonQuit;

@Test
public void start() {
    MainFrame.getInstance().setVisible(true);
    if (showHelpDialog) {
        HelpDialog.getInstance().setVisible(true);
    }
    while(testRunning) {

    }
}
```

And when I pressed quit button testRunning variable is set to false.

Comment: Could you show us the code your already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is, that your blocking the Thread with your UI by executing your loop.

I made an little example with an JFrame. This frame has a JButton as big as the frame. In an Thread is and Loop working until the Button is pressed:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    //to setThe state of the loop
    public static boolean continueLoop = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(400, 400);
        frame.setSize(d);

        //Add a button to close the programm or end the loop
        JButton b = new JButton("Close");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                continueLoop = false;
                //Enable this if you want to close the programm
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // Start a Thread with your endless loop in it
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 1;
                while(continueLoop)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        System.out.println("Try: " + i);
                        i++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();

        // Add a button and set de Frame visible
        frame.add(b);       
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Hope that helps!

PS: this is the fastest example i could think of. Note that there are better ways to add a state-controled loop to your UI. For example I used static variables for my example - you should not do that in your application - except it really necessary.

Comment: @user3552976 Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: thanks I will try this solution later, now I have other task to do. I give an answer as soon as I try this.

Comment: it doesnt work, while i press button the variable change value to false but when I print it in while loop is set on true, I have no idea why

Comment: @user3552976 have you tried my code in a stand alone porject or applied to your code?

Comment: I put it to my code. But the main problem is that it runs in testng method, when I run it as normal method it works fine but when use testng annotation the loop is not breaking. Also I try to put GUI (setVisible method) in the thread and try to wait to end this thread but it also doesnt work

Comment: Ok, i solve my problem. I changed in your code stop condition, it depends on visibility of main window gui. if visibility is set to false the loop break and application stop executing. thanks for help